# find where next() goes to

Tags: node.js, express

I have a simple module that authenticates. If the user is not authenticated I use this function to move him forward :

```
function forbidden() {
    return next({ status: 403 });
}
```

I can't seem to find what's the `next` function that picks this up in case of `403`. Is there a way I can see all the middleware stack ?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you rather just generate a 403 response instead of passing your object down the middleware chain?

Comment: He probably wants to handle the error with a middleware.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeLeclerc you are correct

Comment: That said, you should not be able to see which function is called next. The middleware design is good because it impose a way to abstract the different layers of your logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next` is always a synthetic function that connect creates to know when your middleware is done and it's time to proceed either down the regular middleware stack (if no error is passed to `next`) or the error handling middleware stack (when an error is passed to `next` as in your example). So it's always going to be the same function, but you can explore with node-inspector if you want to peek at the state of the connect middleware stack for educational purposes. Even then since most functions added to the connect middleware are coded as anonymous functions, the middleware stack Array is just going to look like `[Function, Function, Function]` and not be very illuminating.